# How to add controls to a automatic Jquery slideshow scrolling left/right relative to the slide position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function SlideDivSection(){
 var items = ['banner1', 'banner2', 'banner3', 'banner4', 'banner5'];
 var container = $('#banner');
 var root = document.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ? document.body:document.documentElement;
 var isVerticalScrollbar = root.scrollHeight > root.clientHeight;
 if(isVerticalScrollbar == false){
  var item_width = window.screen.availWidth - 17;
 } else {
  var item_width = window.screen.availWidth;
 }
 
 window.setInterval(function(){
  var first = $('.banner:first', container);
  var faux_id = first.attr('id')+'faux';
  var faux_elem = $($('<div/>').append(first.clone()).html()).attr('id', faux_id).css({
   left:item_width * items.length
     })
     container.append(faux_elem);
     faux_elem = $('#'+faux_id, container);
 
     $('.banner', container).animate({
   left:'-='+item_width
     }, 2000, function(){
   first.remove();
     faux_elem.attr('id', faux_elem.attr('id').replace('faux', ''))
     })
 }, 3000)
}

$(function(){
 SlideDivSection();
});
```

```css
img, video, canvas{
 max-width:100%;
}

.menu{
 width:20%;
 height:100%;
 float:left;
 align-self:center;
 font:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align:center;
}

.menu a{
 color:#FFFFFF;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.menu a:hover{
 color:#CCCCCC;
}

.submenu{
 width:11%;
 height:100%;
 float:left;
 align-self:center;
 text-align:center;
}

.submenu a{
 text-decoration:none;
}

.submenu a:hover{
 
}

.banner_botoes{
 width:18%;
 height:100%;
 float:left;
 z-index:2;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:thin;
 border-color:#000000;
 border-radius:25px;
}

.banner_botoes:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
 border-color:#99FFFF;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

.banner{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
    top:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.destaque{
 top:0px;
 width:25%;
 height:100%;
 float:left;
}

#container{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:1350px;
}

#cabecalho{
 top:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:4%;
 display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
 background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#cabecalho2_produtos{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:8%;
 display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

#cabecalho2_fragrancias{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:5%;
 display:flex;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#cabecalho2_clientes{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:5%;
 display:flex;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#menu{
 margin:auto;
 width:80%;
}

#conteudo_produtos{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:68%;
}

#conteudo_fragrancias{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:65%;
}

#conteudo_clientes{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:65%;
}

#conteudo_suporte{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:70%;
}

#banner{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:47%;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#banner_botoes{
 position:relative;
 left:45%;
 top:85%;
 width:10%;
 height:2%;
 z-index:1;
}

#banner2{
 left:100%;
 background-color:#000000;
}

#banner3{
 left:200%;
 background-color:#333333;
}

#banner4{
 left:300%;
 background-color:#666666;
}

#banner5{
 left:400%;
 background-color:#999999;
}

#destaques{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:15%;
}

#faixa{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:6%;
}

#rodape{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:28%;
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <div id="cabecalho">
     <div id="menu">
            <div id="menu1" class="menu"><a href="index.php"><b>Home</b></a></div>
            <div id="menu2" class="menu"><a href="produtos.php">Produtos</a></div>
            <div id="menu3" class="menu"><a href="fragrancias.php">Fragrâncias</a></div>
            <div id="menu4" class="menu"><a href="clientes_atividades.php">Clientes e Atividades</a></div>
            <div id="menu5" class="menu"><a href="suporte.php">Suporte</a></div>
        </div>
   </div>
    <div id="banner">
     <div id="banner_botoes">
         <div id="banner_botao1" class="banner_botoes"></div>
            <div id="banner_botao2" class="banner_botoes"></div>
            <div id="banner_botao3" class="banner_botoes"></div>
            <div id="banner_botao4" class="banner_botoes"></div>
            <div id="banner_botao5" class="banner_botoes"></div>
        </div>
     <div id="banner1" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
        <div id="banner2" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
        <div id="banner3" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
        <div id="banner4" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
        <div id="banner5" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
    </div>
   <div id="destaques">
     <div id="destaque1" class="destaque"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
        <div id="destaque2" class="destaque"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
        <div id="destaque3" class="destaque"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
        <div id="destaque4" class="destaque"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
    </div>
   <div id="faixa"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
   <div id="rodape"></div>
</div>
```

I have the following Jquery slideshow:

```
function SlideDivSection(){
var items = ['banner1', 'banner2', 'banner3', 'banner4', 'banner5'];
var container = $('#banner');
var root = document.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ? document.body:document.documentElement;
var isVerticalScrollbar = root.scrollHeight > root.clientHeight;
if(isVerticalScrollbar == false){
    var item_width = window.screen.availWidth - 17;
} else {
    var item_width = window.screen.availWidth;
}

window.setInterval(function(){
    var first = $('.banner:first', container);
    var faux_id = first.attr('id')+'faux';
    var faux_elem = $($('<div/>').append(first.clone()).html()).attr('id', faux_id).css({
        left:item_width * items.length
    })
    container.append(faux_elem);
    faux_elem = $('#'+faux_id, container);

    $('.banner', container).animate({
        left:'-='+item_width
    }, 2000, function(){
        first.remove();
        faux_elem.attr('id', faux_elem.attr('id').replace('faux', ''))
    })
}, 3000); }// end of SlideDivSection

$(function(){ SlideDivSection(); });
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
    <div id="banner_botoes">
        <div id="banner_botao1" class="banner_botoes"></div>
        <div id="banner_botao2" class="banner_botoes"></div>
        <div id="banner_botao3" class="banner_botoes"></div>
        <div id="banner_botao4" class="banner_botoes"></div>
        <div id="banner_botao5" class="banner_botoes"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="banner1" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
    <div id="banner2" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
    <div id="banner3" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
    <div id="banner4" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
    <div id="banner5" class="banner"><img width="100%" height="100%" src="" /></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#banner{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:47%;
overflow:hidden; }

#banner_botoes{
position:relative;
left:45%;
top:85%;
width:10%;
height:2%;
z-index:1; }

#banner2{
left:100%;
background-color:#000000; }

#banner3{
left:200%;
background-color:#333333; }

#banner4{
left:300%;
background-color:#666666; }

#banner5{
left:400%;
background-color:#999999; }

.banner_botoes{
width:18%;
height:100%;
float:left;
z-index:2;
border-style:solid;
border-width:thin;
border-color:#000000;
border-radius:25px; }

.banner_botoes:hover{
cursor:pointer;
border-color:#99FFFF;
background-color:#FFFFFF; }

.banner{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%; }
```

And its working ok. However, I want to make make the div "banner_botoes" to be a control to this slideshow, making it slide left or right onClick relative to the "banner" position, and then resume the slideshow.

To be more precise, I want it to be exactly like the slideshow on the Apple BR website: www.apple.com/br

Thanks so much for the attention and sorry for any english mystakes in my question.

Comment: create a fiddle plz - that much code is inhuman to read ;)

Comment: I added but the full html or else i would have to edit the height of the elements. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var items="";
var container ="";
var root="";
var isVerticalScrollbar="";
var autoSlide="";
function SlideDivSection(){
items = ['banner1', 'banner2', 'banner3', 'banner4', 'banner5'];
container = $('#banner');
root = document.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ? document.body:document.documentElement;
isVerticalScrollbar = root.scrollHeight > root.clientHeight;
if(isVerticalScrollbar == false){
    var item_width = window.screen.availWidth - 17;
} else {
    var item_width = window.screen.availWidth;
}

autoSlide = window.setInterval(function(){
  slideChange(0);

}, 3000); }// end of SlideDivSection

function slideChange(slideDir){
      var first = $('.banner:first', container);
    var faux_id = first.attr('id')+'faux';
    var faux_elem = $($('<div/>').append(first.clone()).html()).attr('id', faux_id).css({
        left:item_width * items.length
    })
    container.append(faux_elem);
    faux_elem = $('#'+faux_id, container);
    if(slideDir==1){
    $('.banner', container).animate({
        left:'+='+item_width
    }, 2000, function(){
        first.remove();
        faux_elem.attr('id', faux_elem.attr('id').replace('faux', ''))
    })
    }else{
      
          $('.banner', container).animate({
        left:'-='+item_width
    }, 2000, function(){
        first.remove();
        faux_elem.attr('id', faux_elem.attr('id').replace('faux', ''))
    })
      }
  }

function slideControl(strAction){
  if(slideControl=="Stop"){
    clearInterval(autoSlide);
    
    }else if(slideControl=="Play"){
      autoSlide = window.setInterval(function(){
  slideChange(0);

}, 3000); }
      
      }else if(slideControl=="Next"){
        slideChange(0);
        
        }else if(slideControl=="Back"){
          slideChange(1);
          
          }
  
  }

$(function(){ SlideDivSection(); });
```

Above slideControl("Next") proceeds 1; slideControl("Back") goes back 1; slideControl("Stop") stops the interval and slideControl("Play") starts the interval.

Comment: in this answer, should I add a onClick="slideControl('next');" in my "banner_botao1" div?